# Add progress indicator to FireStoreRecyclerAdapter and maintain recyclerviev visibility after app resume

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using firebase to build my apps, however, when I open the app, it takes some time to show in recyclerview. Also,when I resume the activity after some time the recyclerview does not show.

1. How can I add progress indicator to appear to the user when still loading data?
2. How can I solve the problem of recyclerview disappearing?

Comment: No, am only calling startListening() in onStart() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add progress indicator to appear to the user when still loading data?
>
> How can I solve the problem of recyclerview disappearing?

Regarding the first one, all you need is to add a progress dialog or progress bar.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Regarding the second question:

When you go to another activity and then press the back button, `onResume()` is getting triggered that is why there is no data. So it is better to retrieve the data in `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()`

[image: lifecycle]

Comment: Great @Peter how can I attach a progressbar to FireStoreRecyclerAdapter's loading process? especially when I have several adapters in one activity and I want to monitor one on a button-click event  when the user clicks a button immediately after starting activity and adapter has not loaded. I have tried various ways but failed

Comment: @GeekGuy just add a progress bar in the code before the code where you retrieve data and give it some seconds also